# What automatic citation/bibliography programs are well-designed for law papers?

Tags: citation-style, law

I have tried Mendeley for citations and bibliography for writing law papers at my university, but it seems not to be designed for legal citations.

For example, when I want to add a Case file as an item in mendeley, and choose "case" as the item's type, it asks for "volume" rather than "case number", which causes the citation to be incorrectly formatted.

So which citation program is well-adapted to legal citations? Which program(s) should I use?

e.g. I'm using a citation style like OSCALA or Bluebook.

Comment: So sad this is almost two years old and doesn't have any traction. I guess the subset of people with time, legal skill and computer skill to design something is terribly tiny.